# Solving Summation and limit together

Tags: integration, limits, summation

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty (r/n)^n = $$

How to proceed with such question

I tried putting

r/n=t
dr/n=it

Which does not convert it to integration
Form so how to calculate

Comment: Maybe you meant $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{r^n}{n^{n+1}}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\ n\in\mathbb{N},$

$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{r=\infty} \left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^n = \infty.$$

So the limit of $\ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=0}^{r=\infty} \left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^n\ $ as $\ n\to\infty\ $ is $\ \infty.$

Comment: Another downvote without reason. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Anusha Yes it is. Please check your question is copied down correctly.